# How to show the save dialog using HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, html

How can I force the save file download dialog box when I click an `<a>` tag?. There is a PDF file available on a remote server and when a user clicks that link we want to download that PDF file to their local system.

Thanks

Comment: Open/Save? What do you want the user to open?

Comment: Read my post carefully. 'when user clicks that link we want to download that pdf file to a local system.' This is very clear I think?

EDIT: I'll change my title. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when you link a file that file will always display inside of the browser because the browser loads it and automatically determines the content type based on the file extension. So when you click on a link like a jpg image pdf etc the browser knows it's an image/file and will display that file. You can of course always use the browser short cut menu and use the Save Target As option to save the file to disk.

If you want to do this automatically when a link is clicked from the server side, you have to send the file back yourself rather and add a couple of custom headers to the output. The way to do this is to use `Response.TransmitFile()` to explicitly send the file from your ASP.NET application and then add the Content Type and Content-Disposition headers.

So You neded to use headers liek below:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
```

Here is an exapmle might help you :

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET

Answer (score 3):

change your header values..

Ex
`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"')`

```
path = "path/to/file.pdf";
$filename = "file.pdf";
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  // For Gecko browsers mainly
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)) . ' GMT');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');  // For download resume
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));  // File size
header('Content-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');  // Change this mime type if the file is not PDF
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);  // Make the browser display the Save As dialog
```

Answer (score -6):

What he is looking for is not a open save dialogue while downloading something from the host.

He is looking to open a file from the client's file system. You must use the input type file, to do so. But you will not get much privileges to manipulate that using javascript.

And there is no way to prompt a window's save dialogue through standard html.

We need ActiveX or Flash to do it.